# inputted string being separated into 2 vars by space when inputted in an object

Tags: java, arrays, object

Have a list of objects and a method to create and add an object to said list below. Thing is, if I type in a name with a space, it will fill in the second spaced string as an artist. For example if a name "one two" is entered, "one" will be stored in the name variable while "two" will be stored in artist.

```
                    System.out.println("Enter song name: ");
                    name = keyboard.next();
                    
                    System.out.println("Enter song artist: ");
                    artist = keyboard.next();
                    
                    System.out.println("Enter song runtime: ");
                    runtime = keyboard.nextInt();
                    
                    if (runtime <= 0) 
                        {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input, try again.");
                        break;
                        }//if
                    
                    System.out.println("Enter song price: ");
                    price = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    
                    if (price <= 0) 
                        {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input, try again.");
                        break;
                        }//if
                    
                    newSong = new SongMoretti(name, artist, runtime, price);
                        
                    ok = thePlaylist.addToPlayist(newSong);
                    
                    if (ok == true)
                        System.out.println("Song added");
                    else 
                        System.out.println("Song not added");
                    break;
```

Comment: Use `keyboard.nextLine()` to read the entire line, including spaces.

Comment: `if (ok == true)` is poor style. `if (ok)` is sufficient. And you should braces. Even if they're optional.